# How to call wp_list_comments() with callback outside the loop

Tags: theme-development, comments

the template function as a callback argument of `wp_list_comments` function, and the template function takes three args:`$comment, $args, $depth`, like the template function that defined in the theme `twentyeleven`'s functions.php,

```
function twentyeleven_comment( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
$GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
switch ( $comment->comment_type ) :
    case 'pingback' :
    case 'trackback' :
?>
<li class="post pingback">
    <p><?php _e( 'Pingback:', 'twentyeleven' ); ?> <?php comment_author_link(); ?><?php edit_comment_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyeleven' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?></p>
<?php
     /** and more ... **/
```

I want to invoke this function in another place, and I have the `$comment` reference to a comment, but I don't know how to set the `$args` and `$depth` variables. I know the value of `$depth` or `$args` can be changed in the admin settings, so, I can't just set `$depth` to 5 or whatever a number.

How can I get the `$args` and `$depth` ???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to invoke the twentyeleven_comment() function, not the `wp_list_comments()` function. @s_ha_dum, you changed the question title?

Comment: `twentyeleven_comment()` is a *callback* for `wp_list_comments()`. The function you want to call is **`wp_list_comments()`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have the solution.
first, use the global variable $comment_depth, pass it to `twentyeleven_comment()` function, and in the `twentyeleven_comment()` function, define a new variable named `$defaults` like this:

```
function twentyeleven_comment( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
     $defaults = array('walker' => null, 'max_depth' => '', 'style' => 'ul', 'callback' => null, 'end-callback' => null, 'type' => 'all','page' => '', 'per_page' => '', 'avatar_size' => 32, 'reverse_top_level' => null, 'reverse_children' => '');
     $args = wp_parse_args($args,$defaults);

 /** something else **/
}
```

In another function, invoke `twentyeleven_comment()` function like this:

```
 add_action('comment_post','my_action',10,2);
 function my_action($comment_id,$comment_status){
       $comment_g = &get_comment($comment_id);

       global $comment_depth;  /** here get the $depth  **/
       twentyeleven_comment($comment_g,array(),$comment_depth); /** invoke the function in this way **/

       /*** something else goes here ***/
}
```

I just want to output one comment by the `$comment_ID`。

thanks to those guys who have commented or answered :)

Answer (score 1):

Just go ahead and call it in the same way the tventyeleven does:

```
<?php
                /* Loop through and list the comments. Tell wp_list_comments()
                 * to use twentyeleven_comment() to format the comments.
                 * If you want to overload this in a child theme then you can
                 * define twentyeleven_comment() and that will be used instead.
                 * See twentyeleven_comment() in twentyeleven/functions.php for more.
                 */
                wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'twentyeleven_comment' ) );
            ?>
```

wp_list_comments function will manage $depth and other $args itself (in walker). See [source code of wp_list_comments](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L1412) and the [walker using callback arg](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L1334)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that 'echo' is true

```
wp_list_comments(
            array(
                'avatar_size' => 48,
                'style'       => 'ol',
                'short_ping'  => true,
                'per_page' => get_option('comments_per_page'),
                'echo' => true,
                'callback' => 'comments_function_to_call'
            )
);
```

Comment: But that's the default, isn't it? And as far as I can see it has no impact on whether wp_list_comments (or rather Walker_Comments) calls the callback.

Comment: Add the function comments_function_to_call(); in function.php, it's work fine for me, i had the same issu yesterday and i had fix it like that/